# C If() Statement does not runs even if condition is true

Tags: c

I want to make simple calculator, that counts problems you entered, when user enters `0_0` it prints results of problems user wrote.

```
int a[20], b[20], result[20];
int n = 0;
char operation[20]; // 
printf("Enter:\n");



while(1)
{
    if(a[n] == 0 && operation[n] == '_' && b[n] == 0) // Even user types 0_0 cycles does not breaks
    {
        
        break;
    }
    scanf("%i%c%i", &a[n], &operation[n], &b[n]);
    
    n++;
    
}
```

Why even if I type `0_0` cycles does not breaks. Whats wrong with `a[n], b[n], operation[n]` thanks a lot in advance for answer!

Comment: why is `n` incremented (`n++;`) ? data is captured in previous index and compared against next index, in order to exit the loop.

Comment: a better solution without having array [here](https://onlinegdb.com/HxnSWh6ux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` statement is placed **before** you take the users input. So the `if` never checks the user input but instead checks some uninitialized array values (because `n` is incremented just after the scan).

You need to **read input first** and **then do the `if`**. So simply swap the `if` and the `scanf`

```
if (scanf("%i%c%i", &a[n], &operation[n], &b[n]) != 3)
{
    // Illegal input. Add error handling here... or simply exit like:
    exit(1);
}

if(a[n] == 0 && operation[n] == '_' && b[n] == 0)
{
    
    break;
}

n++;
```

Further notice that you need to make sure that the while stops when `n` reach 20 (i.e. to avoid writing outside the arrays). Perhaps do

```
 while(1) --->  while(n < 20)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have spotted the mistake with a simple dry run.

- Initially `n = 0` and `a[0], b[0], operation[0]` have garbage values.
- Now, the control enters the loop, the condition inside `if` is evaluated. This condition evaluates false because of the above point.
- Now, you're reading the values entered by the user.
- Say, now `n = 0`, and `a[0] = 0, operation[0] = '_' and b[0] = 0` (after entering the values).
- But now, `n` gets incremented to `1`.
- The if condition again evaluates to false because `n` is not `0` now.

This continues for ever (possibly).